# How to prevent webview redirect automatically to mobile version

Tags: android, webview

I have a url that I want to put in a webview.
Let's say it's http://mywebsite.com/index.php.
But the webview always redirect to http://m.mywebsite.com/index.php

I have tried this code but it's not working :

```
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.loadUrl(url);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little bit late, but you can set a computer User-Agent:

```
String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) " +
            "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36";
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);
```

I hope it helps!